# Embedding F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Is there an easy way to embed F# interactive (`fsi.exe`) terminal into an application?  More generally, is the code for `fsi.exe` available to make tweaks to, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for fsi.exe ships along with the CTP (check the license, but eventually I think we eventually want to make it MS-PL, if it is not already).

There is not a particularly easy way to embed it.

Comment: As a reference, the Visual Studio F# Interactive window simply spawns an FSI.exe process and redirects STDIO/STDOUT.

Comment: It's a shame.  I really want to be able to share data like you can with the DLR.