# F# programmatically running .fsx script file

Tags: scripting, f#, f#-interactive

I'm sure this must be something really easy, but I can't seem to make it work.  Let's say I have an `.fsx` script file and want to cause it to be executed programmatically.  I'm guessing someone must have blogged about this at some point, but I can't seem to find an example that performs my simple scenario.  Basically, I want to programmatically duplicate what happens when you right click on an `.fsx` file and choose "Run with F# Interactive..."

Comment: There is a discussion here on embedding the fsi interpreter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563024/embedding-f-interactive

Comment: That is an interesting article, but serious overkill for the scenario I am trying to implement.  Thanks for mentioning it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asked in a comment, you can set `UseShellExecute` to false to avoid opening the Windows shell. This way, you can have your output directly in F# shell:

```
open System.Diagnostics

let execScript script =
    let psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Program Files\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsi.exe")
    psi.Arguments <- script
    psi.UseShellExecute <- false
    let p = Process.Start(psi)
    p.WaitForExit()
    p.ExitCode
```

Comment: Thanks, that does fix an annoying issue in the code snippet I posted.  :)

Answer (score 1):

After randomly messing around with the command line args I finally got it to work.  I feel a little lame answering my own question, but hopefully it will still help someone else.  It turned out my confusion was the proper usage of the command line arguments.  If someone has something more elegant or generally useful than what I put I'll award the answer to you.

```
open System.Diagnostics

let launchExecutable() =
    let proc = new Process()
    proc.StartInfo.FileName <- @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\fsi.exe"
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments <- @"--exec --nologo pathToFSXFile\Test.fsx"
    proc.Start()


launchExecutable();;
```

Comment: I just realized I wrote launchExecutable in camel-case.  Clearly, the functional programming style is turning me to the dark side of the force.  ;)