# load body of function from text file at runtime in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compilation, runtime

I have made a vb project that works with registry and system management but my code is like this:

```
CheckAnswer(question_id)
```

it means that each question has own works with sys registry and sys management and I wanted that the program read each question from file at runtime.
my `CheckAnswer` body function that I made is :

```
Private Sub CheckAnswer(ByVal id As Integer)
    Dim mark As Integer
    mark = 0
    ''''''''''''''''''''''
    Select Case id

        Case 1

            Dim r As Rectangle = Nothing
            If GetTaskBarPosition(r, Me.Handle) Then
                If r.Y = 0 And r.X = 0 Then mark = 1
            End If


        Case 2

            If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\", "TaskbarSizeMove", 1) = 0 Then mark = 1
end case
```

but I wanted to do this work at runtime and say to program that read function from a file not from the source code for flexibility and adding new questions without changing the program source and just with changing the function file.

---

I have searched this site and others for code generation and the other things like this and code provider. I have get a project from "code project" but give me compile errors.

I do not want to generate separate class code because I have implemented imports and libraries in my own class and I want to say the program just which one of them I want to use in my function file.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write VB.Net script files and execute them at runtime using the [VBCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in the future you will be able to make use of the Roslyn compiler if required.

I have a short code example for compiling and running [C# Scripts](http://trelford.com/blog/post/C-Scripting.aspx), to make it work for VB.Net you would simply need to convert the code from C#, and use the VB.Net provider.

Another option would be to use [F#](http://trelford.com/blog/post/fs4vb.aspx) which supports [script files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/09/12/scripting-in-f.aspx) out-of-the-box (extension .fsx)  which can be easily edited and [executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654804/2012417).